# Ruby: how to use Process.spawn to run Ruby code

Tags: ruby

For some reasons, I need to use Ruby `Process.spawn` to run a Ruby lambda. It seems that `Process.spawn` takes a string for shell command.

```rb
task = lambda do
  work()
  otherJobs()
end

Process.spawn(task)  # TypeError: no implicit conversion of Proc into String
```

I wonder how to run Ruby code with `Process.spawn`.

Comment: From the docs it looks like you can use `Process.fork` for this purpose but they mention that it doesn't work on every platform. See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Process.html#method-c-fork

Comment: The documentation is slightly misleading. Unfortunately, the authors of the core library documentation sometimes seem to think that YARV is the only Ruby implementation on the planet. Yes, it is true that `Process::fork` doesn't work on Windows if you are using YARV, but it works just fine in JRuby and probably TruffleRuby as well. In fact, when running on Windows, JRuby is more compatible with Ruby than "Ruby" is.